# How can I increase the length of localstorage using my code by adding different txt1 values

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, web

I have created the below code to add my txt value to localStorage. I am able to add the value with this code but there is bit more requirement for me. I need to get different values of txt1 as different elements in local storage string. With this code I just get only one element in localStorage saying length1 (doesn't matte rhow long the txt1 is. Can anyone help me to solve the problem that how can I change the length of localstorage using txt1 values.

```
let btn1= document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    let txt1= document.getElementById("txt1").value;
    let notes=localStorage.getItem("notes").value;
    const notesObj={txt1:txt1}

    
window.localStorage.setItem("notes",JSON.stringify(notesObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply updating the `txt1` key in your object, but as you need to store multiple values, you should be using as array. Here's a small example:

```js
    // Initializing an array with value 1
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify({ txt1: [1] }))
    let txt1 = 2;
    let notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
    // Updating my next value of txt1, so that it appends to the array
    notes.txt1.push(txt1);
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes))
    // Your output is: txt1: [1, 2]
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")))
```

In your code, you can do as:

```js
// Initialize empty array
localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify({ txt1: [] }));
let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      // When the button is clicked, get the local storage data, and append the new text value
      let notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
      notes.txt1.push(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
      localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes))
      console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")))
    });
```

Comment: I am working witj JSOparse. its showing error jsonparse is undefined                                
      "script.js:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: JSONparse is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> "

Comment: Are you exactly using the Json parse like i did? The capitalisation? JSON.parse

Comment: Try my exact code first and please check if it works in your case. And then you can easily adapt to your logic

Comment: yes, I am using JSON.parse

Comment: I think my push is not working

Comment: let btn1= document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    txt1= document.getElementById("txt1").value;
    txt2=localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify({ txt1: [1] }))
    let notes=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes").value);
    //const notesObj={ 
        //txt1:txt1
    //};
    
   notes.txt1.push(txt1);
   
window.localStorage.setItem("notes",JSON.stringify(notes));
txt1.value="";
console.log(notes);
})//}                                                                         its showing error""undefined" is not valid JSON"

Comment: in your code array comes if we write let text1=2: But, I want this array formation automatically when I type new text in my web html

Comment: I've added a new snippet in my ans. Can you try it?

Comment: yes its working. can u find what is wrong with this let btn1= document.getElementById("btn1");
    btn1.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        txt1= document.getElementById("txt1").value;
        
        notes=localStorage.getItem("notes").value;
        if(notes == null){
            notesObj=[];
            }
              /else{
                  notesObj= JSON.parse("notes");
                }
        
       notesObj.push(txt1);
       
    window.localStorage.setItem("notes",JSON.stringify(notesObj));
    txt1.value="";
    console.log(notesObj);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247201/discussion-between-deepak-and-navjot-singh).

Comment: hlo deepak, i need to add one more entry that will change name of notes from note1, note2 so on to thenew names that I will entre. How I can do that with your code that you have provided above. can you give me your whatsap number so that I can communicate with you.